# given money to pay for food, housing, etc

Tags: grammar

> an advanced student at a university who is given money **to** pay for food, housing, etc. : a graduate student who has been granted a fellowship

---

Does "**to**" mean "*with which they could*" or "*in order to*"?

Comment: The meaning of your two analyses is the same.  The purpose of the money is the same as the purpose of giving them the money.  So I don't know how much you will learn from this particular example.

Comment: @JamesK I wonder if "**to**" is the same as the "*to*" in "*an effort to do something*".

Comment: It might help to note that the "adverb of purpose" element ***to pay for food, housing, etc.*** is ***syntactically optional***. But the "head noun" of the noun phrase for what was given *(**money**)* must be present or it won't be syntactically valid.

Comment: It means _in order to pay_ or _for the purpose of paying_.

Comment: Syntactically speaking, it's the same ***to*** in both parsings, because whether it adjectivally modifies ***money*** or adverbially modifies ***given***, the word ***to*** is in both cases an ***infinitive verb marker***.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that it is ambiguous who pays for food, housing, etc. It could be "an advanced student" or "someone else who gives money to an advanced student". So I think that, to remove this ambiguity, "in order for them" or "for them" should be inserted just before "to pay for food, housing, etc." What do you think about that?

Comment: I don't understand what you're getting at. It's the "advanced student" who pays - ***using*** money given ton him by persons unspecified. I hope that by now you understand that (to Anglophones, at least) "an effort to do something" and "in order to [do something]" are ***the same thing***. And in most contexts where ***to*** means ***in order to***, it's entirely a stylistic choice whether to use one word or three.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It means both because they are both the same:

> ... an advanced student at a university who is given money **which he can use** to pay for food, housing, etc.

> ... an advanced student at a university who is given money **in order to** to pay for food, housing, etc.